# Labels dropping off PDF when exported in QGIS with EasyCustomLabeling plugin?

Tags: qgis, labeling, export

I'm having an issue with two particular labels on two separate layers in QGIS. The label layers having being created using the EasyCustomLabeling plugin.

I'm creating an A0 printout with an OS base map and c.100 points with labels(All created with the EasyCustomLabeling plugin) The only solution I have at the moment is to drop the DPI on the export resolution in the composer. However at 1:7500 @ A0 the DPI is now so low that it is causing the base map to appear blurry when printed. Even when the DPI is dropped to 120 one of the two problem labels will still not appear.

I have ensured that **Show all Labels for this layer (including colliding labels)** is checked as well as setting the weighting on the **Discourage labels from covering features** to High Weight for all the layers with labels.

All of my labels are horizontal and none are curved.

Comment: So the labels show up in the print composer, but they're missing from the exported pdf?

Comment: Yes, everything shows in the print composer but when the PDF is exported through the composer the 2 labels drop off.

Comment: Strange. That's not how the print composer is supposed to behave. If you refresh the print composer view, are the labels still there?

Answer (score -1):

I've the same problem. The only solution I found is to run the extension with Qgis2, save the shapefile created and open it in Qgis 3 with a saved style.